# Group two colums regardless of their order - Mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this table to arrange mails in my website

```
mail_id   from   to    mail
   1        a     b    ....
   2        a     b    ....
   3        b     a    ....
   4        a     c    ....
   5        a     c    ....
```

Now, i want to choose a unique from-to or to-from pair. doesn't matter their placement. This is the desired results

```
from  to
 a    b
 a    c
```

I am using GROUP BY for from and to columns but  it gives me both a-b and b-a

`select * from mail group by from, to`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT LEAST(FROM,TO),GREATEST(FROM, TO)
     from MAIL
     GROUP BY LEAST(FROM,TO),GREATEST(FROM, TO)
```

Might do it.

Comment: @Lotz this solution is working. however its getting first occurence of a match(`mail id = 1`). Is there a way to get last occurance for a-b pair(`mail-id = 3`). actually i am trying to get higher `datetime` value, as you may have guessed...

Comment: Add `MAX(MAIL_ID)` into your select.  Not sure what you mean about `datetime` as that does nor appear in your table or required results.  Also, MySQL has some craziness around `GROUP BY`. You should read up on how it works properly so you don't fall into the "here's some random results" trap.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from mail 
where from<to
group by from, to
```

Comment: from<to what that means? never seen it before. a little explanation please

Comment: it's like you already get `b` in `to` column then you are checking `> from` which means you don't want less values as you already got less value in  `to` column

Comment: what means less value? alphabeticly behind?

Comment: yes alphabetically less means you got `b` in `to` column so you don't want `b` again in `from` column as you got b in `to` column

Comment: This won't work where you have only one pair and `to>from`